# Preview mode shows only a part of object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh

I have a problem while in preview mode. It cuts my obj at different angles when I'm rotating around it.

- Works only on this particular object
- Doesn't matter if in Obj or Edit mode
- Render works ok
- Clipping set to minimum
- Real life scale obj

[Blend file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=90482243591724137944)

Also sometimes when I rotate around whole obj selected in Edit mode, everything disappears.

[[image: Render]Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noSm2.png)
[image]
[[image]Previews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJjkJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh seems to be severely corrupted and causing all manner of issues and unexpected behavior, including rendering artifacts and badly computed center for rotating view in *Edit Mode*.

To clean it up select you object, enter *Edit Mode*, make sure you are in *Vertex Selection* mode, and switch to *Wireframe* shading mode.

Select all vertex with *Border Select* operator (do not use the <kbd>A</kbd>  *Select All* operator) then hit <kbd>P</kbd> to separate it into a new object.

If you switch back to *Object Mode* you should now have to objects, a new one containing the actual geometry, and a second one with what appears to be loose edges.

Erase the loose edges and and it should fix your issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked as I need.
It was just a placeholder as you can see, but this issue with preview really bothered me.

And I've learned something new, thanks again ;)